# What are different ways to determine how an explanatory variable affect a target variable?

Tags: econometrics, regression, autoregressive, machine-learning

I'm trying to determine a quantitative value by which a target variable change (inflation) by changing an indicator variable (interest rate).

The industry basically uses linear models such as VAR. Are there state of the art approaches to capture such relationship?

Comment: This is quite a broad topic, more advanced versions of VAR are still considered state of the art, but there are lot of ways how to model it. Which way is the best depends on multiple factors such as what sort of data you have at your disposal. Without somehow narrowing it down it is probably not feasible to provide answer to such broad question in SE format